# Should I use a proxy/reverse proxy?

Tags: web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have some web servers in the same network, each of them with it's own IP.

Now I want to a proxy to "transfer" the request to the correct server according to the requested domain.

Everything was fine until I realized that all requests are considered from the proxy instead of the original IP.

How can I make the request send it's original IP in the TCP/IP?

I don't want to use get variables or this kind of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the X-Forwarded-For Header for this.
it is for what i understand exactly designed to solve your problem.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For for details.

Answer (score 1):

### [Squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/)

Your understanding of proxies is correct.

What you want to do is achievable depending on which proxy you are using.

If you are using [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as your proxy you can achieve this with a rewrite rule in the squid.conf file.